# Install non-conda packages in Anaconda on air-gapped machine

Tags: python, anaconda, package, offline, conda

Trying to get pyNastran onto an air-gapped machine with a new install of Anaconda.

I've tried `conda install pyNastran-0.7.1.zip` on the zipped source code, and `conda install setup.py` inside the unzipped folder. Both commands cause `conda` to try to get "package metadata" from `https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs` and fail when they can't reach the server, despite this being the method suggested [here](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/faq.html#how-do-i-install-packages-on-a-non-networked-machine).

`python setup.py install` fails due to `setuptools` not being installed, and installing `setuptools` through python fails, apparently due to `setuptools` not being installed (?!).

I must be doing something wrong here.  How do I get this to install?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`conda` can only work with `tar.bz2` files.

So, unzip `pyNastran-0.7.1.zip` and re-zip as `pyNastran-0.7.1.tar.bz2` using some zipping tool.

Now, you need to tell `conda` to work offline with `--offline`:

```
conda install  --offline  pyNastran-0.7.1.tar.bz2
```

Comment: Well, it's an improvement, but now I'm getting another error:  `PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: ' ' Package missing in current win-64 channels: \n pynastran-0.7.1.zip`.  Do I need to put the zip file anywhere in particular before I install it?

Comment: I'm not sure if  `conda` can use `zip` files. Try to  make an `tar.bz2` from the zip file (unzip and re-zip in the other format).

Comment: Great. I Incorporated that into the answer.

Comment: @Mike Müller Is your answer a general, proper and safe rule to install non-conda packages in the Anaconda python environment? I.e., if I were to install python-pptx, which is not on a list of Anaconda packages ("All"), is it recommended to follow your answer or is there a better way to do it? I am asking, because you have a different answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57326043/how-to-install-packages-in-conda-that-are-not-available-in-anaconda-conda4-7?rq=1

Comment: The OP already has `conda` package on his machine but no internet connection. The other answer you refer to  works if the package is only available via PyPi and the user does have an Internet connection. The installation uses `pip`, which installs from PyPi.

Comment: @Mike Müller: Thank you for your replay. Probably the most generalistic approach to installing non-conda packed packages in a conda environment can be found here: https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/introduction.html. Thi is what I was looking for in the first place.

Comment: I know conda-forge und use it intensively. It does not apply to this question because the conda package is already on the computer of the of the user.