# How to install packages in conda that are not available in anaconda

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

*I want to install a package (of python) using conda, but says not available in repo.anaconda.com/......., how could I install it* ?

The specific package that I tried to install is `edx-dl` ([link of the github repo](https://github.com/coursera-dl/edx-dl)) using the code `conda install edx-dl`. This code works fine with `pip` but not with `conda`.

*For example*, in pip if I type `pip install edx-dl` was able to install the package when I was using python base without anaconda. But now with conda it says it is not available in anaconda repo. So if a package that are not available in anaconda, can be installed?

So to generalize, **is there any way to download and install packages of python using `conda` which are not available in repo.anaconda.com**?

*Note that, I do not use base python, rather currently using anaconda. So, can't use `pip` to install that package.*

Thanks!

---

*Error message that I got*:

(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>`conda install edx-dl`

WARNING conda.base.context:use_only_tar_bz2(632): Conda is constrained to only using the old .tar.bz2 file format because you have conda-build installed, and it is <3.18.3.  Update or remove conda-build to get smaller downloads and faster extractions.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- edx-dl

Current channels:

- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

```
https://anaconda.org
```

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

Comment: `is there any way to download and install packages of python using conda which are not available in repo.anaconda.com` -> you either have to re-package it as a conda-package (e.g. with conda-forge) , or use use pip install.

Comment: Why not open anaconda prompt, and type pip install whatever? That will install the thing in your global conda environment. If you want to install it in a specific environment then use Kacper's answer.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

in terminal type:

```
conda activate <env_name>
```

then:

```
pip install edx-dl
```

will work on conda env this library

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried to upvote you but since I am new, couldn't do so. Following your answer, bellow I have written the full code.

Comment: **Note:** Make sure to verify first that `pip` refers to the one installed in the environment, otherwise you could end up installing outside the intended environment. E.g., after activating, check `which pip`.

Answer (score 10):

*Thanks @[Kasper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11409756/kacper) for your answer. Following your answer, I was able to solve the problem. Here I give the complete procedure for anyone who is new.*

**Step 1**: Open "Anaconda Prompt". (I opened as "Run as Administrator" to avoid any problem in installation.)

**Step 2**: type `conda info --envs` to cheek your available environments.

- one environment for sure you should have is `base` & another one
  `Classes_and_Inheritance` also should appear.
- I had PyCharm installed, so with that I had to open some projects. So, I had some additional environments too.

**Step 3**: type `conda activate <environment_name>`

- this *environment_name* should be substituted by your preferred environment
  (i.e. `base`,  `Classes_and_Inheritance` or any other environment
  that you have created. )
- In my case, I used `conda activate PyCharm_Proj`, but if you want, you can use this `conda activate base`

**Step 4**: type `pip install <package_name>`. The *package_name* should be substituted by the name of the package name you want to install. (i.e. in my case I typed `pip install edx-dl`)