# How can I get python packages to work on mac m1?

Tags: python, package, apple-m1, python-venv

I am playing around with building an instagram bot using instapy, but I am getting the following error when trying to `import instapy` when using a Mac M1 chip.

```
ImportError: dlopen(/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/cygrpc.cpython-310-darwin.so' (no such file)
```

I've actually been having a tough time with python packages recently after getting a mac m1. I can't seem to find anything on how to get some of these packages to work.

How can I resolve this issue and fix other packages that are having issues?

Answer (score 0):

`Python2` comes with MacOS, so `pip install x` may point towards `Python2`. Try the following:

```
pip3.10 install instapy
```

Comment: I still get the same error when running `from instapy import InstaPy`

Comment: Do you have multiple python installations?

Comment: What IDE and/or environment are you using?

Comment: Using python 3.10.2 in a venv within VS Code using `python -m venv`

Comment: Is your `python 3.10.2` the `arm64` version? rather than `64bit`. "`incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')`"

Comment: Sorry but idk how to check that. What command can I run?

Comment: Possibly "`cmd + shift + p`" then "`select python interpreter`"??. Not sure if this works for venv tho

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243311/discussion-between-colton-c-and-freddy-mcloughlan).

Comment: I see only 64bit versions. Do I need arm64 to run instapy?

Comment: I solved a lot of packages problems using conda. But there are some that conda does not have on its repositories. For these, I have no idea on how I should solve. If anyone has an idea, please...

Comment: @noStaleReads, have you tried [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57326043/how-to-install-packages-in-conda-that-are-not-available-in-anaconda)

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan No, but in the meantime I tried [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/423324) and after almost 2 days on it, it worked to me! Thank you for your time Freddy =)

Comment: @noStaleReads No problem. Don't forget that you can always [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)