# jupyter does not install into environment using anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

code

```
pip3 install jupyter
```

installs jupyter to base environment within anaconda - I want to install to an environment i have created.
Any fixes for installing into an environment other than base root?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Pip to install packages to Anaconda Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060382/using-pip-to-install-packages-to-anaconda-environment)? Or [How to install packages in conda that are not available in anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57326043/8508004)?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to install to an already created environment, you will have to first activate that environment.

```
conda activate <name of env>
```

if successful you will see the name of the env the left side of your terminal prompt.

then you can install packages like usual.

```
pip3 install jupyter
```

Hope this helps!